# How do I find out specifics of lobbying efforts?

Tags: united-states, lobbying

Is there any way that a normal citizen can find out the specifics of money spent on lobbying for or against specific topics, and what the net effects of the lobbying are?

Answer (score 2):

This site called http://www.opensecrets.org seems to have a lot of data regarding lobbying spending

[Total Lobbying](http://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/)

[Lobbying on Bureau of Labor Statistics](https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/agencysum.php?id=169)

[Lobbying on Bureau of Justice](http://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/agencysum.php?id=158)

[Lobbying on Pharmaceuticals/Health Products](http://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/indusclient.php?id=H04)

Comment: The links look interesting but How can I use them to understand what is going on behind the scenes with lobbing efforts

Comment: @DrunkenSanta9035768   You might want to locate the sources that opensecrets.org relies on.